# Cron Job on cPanel not running

Tags: php, mysqli, cron, cpanel, whm

I'm trying to run a cronjob in cPanel which gives me the following error:

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/example/public_html/new_facebook_csv/csv_generator1.php:180

If run that file through browser by using the link example.com/new_facebook_csv/csv_generator1.php i get the right resaults without any errors, but if i try to run it with a cron job i get the error "Class 'mysqli' not found".

The cron job I'm running is the following:

```
php /home/example/public_html/new_facebook_csv/csv_generator1.php > /home/example/public_html/new_facebook_csv/facebook.log
```

and here is the logs i get after the cron job:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.22
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /home/example/public_html/new_facebook_csv/csv_generator1.php:180
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in <b>/home/example/public_html/new_facebook_csv/csv_generator1.php</b> on line <b>180</b><br />
```

I added the mysqli extension in the php.ini (extension=php_mysql.dll) but not luck with that.

Also check if mysqli is installed to my server with this commaned:

```
php -m|grep mysql
```

and that was my output

```
mysqli
mysqlnd
pdo_mysql
```

which means that mysql is installed to my server

Comment: Did you add the extension for PHP cli? I mean which php.ini did you change

Comment: I created a new php.ini file inside the same folder with the executable file (/home/example/public_html/php.ini)

Comment: it sounds like the version of PHP used by cron is not picking that up.
Perhaps use explicit php  i.e. /usr/bin/php7.4 myscript.php and update the php.ini for that if its meant to be server wide. Otherwise I think you can include the ini like
/usr/bin/php7.4 -c /path/to/custom/ini myscript.php

Comment: Including the php.ini inside the cron command solved my problem. Thank you a lot!

Comment: The question title is misleading; the job is running - but it's producing errors.

Answer (score 0):

try with curl like `/usr/bin/curl example.com/new_facebook_csv/csv_generator1.php`

or you can use wget `wget -q -O- example.com/new_facebook_csv/csv_generator1.php`

Comment: Seems likes curl is running succesfull with no errors. But still i dont get why i was getting the mysqli error

Comment: curl is doing a http request so a different php is used. command line/cron would run a different one

Comment: So, mysqli is enebled for http request and not for command line/cron request?

Comment: i think that's whats happening

Answer (score 0):

This is how I scheduled a cron job in cPanel through GoDaddy that runs the script and includes MYSQLI:

```
curl -s "https://yourwebsite.com/phpscript.php"
```

[image]

I tried many variations including cPanel's example on running a PHP script with a cron job. I tried php in front of the script path, and the same format you used above, as well as the suggested answers and I received the same errors. Just using curl -s and then the url of your php script will do the trick.